# How can I allow a user to post to Twitter from my JavaScript/PhoneGap application?

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to implement a little Javascript/PhoneGap utility that can post a tweet on twitter.

So far I've got this:

```
var authorize_url = 'https://oauth.twitter.com/2/authorize';
authorize_url += '?oauth_callback_url=' + encodeURIComponent(mycallbackUrl);
authorize_url += '&oauth_mode=flow_web_client';
authorize_url += '&oauth_client_identifier=' +*****;
authorize_url += '&response_type=token';
authorize_url += '&client_id' + *****;
```

This resulting URL will show me the twitter login screen, and after I login, the callback url is shown with two paramaters; **oauth_access_token** and **oauth_bridge_code**

So far so good, but the next part is confusing me.

Is this oauth_access_token I'm getting enough to do a tweet on behalf of the user? Or do I have to take further authentication steps? If not, how can I use the token in the call to http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json to actually post a tweet?

The twitter API docs can't help me out so all help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an unsupported method of authentication that Twitter could change/break at anytime. It is recommended that you use the officially supported OAuth flow. https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

Comment: Hi Abraham, thanks for your help! I've extracted the mentioned authorize_url from the @Anywhere javascript library which is (as far as I know) officially supported by twitter. So I guess they use a similar URL (https://oauth.twitter.com/2/<something here>) to post a tweet when using @Anywhere. Can this be true?

Comment: The documented features of @anywhere like the tweetbox, hovercard, etc are public but the underlying authentication is considered private and not supported for third party developers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mediaSource = "http://twitter.com/home?status={TITLE}";
mediaSource = mediaSource.replace('{TITLE}',"Text to share in Twitter");

window.location = mediaSource;
```

this may help you.